# What is meant by the term 'biosynthetic origin'?

Tags: biochemistry

I keep seeing the term biosynthetic origin used in medicinal related papers.

Does it just refer to the biological precursors to the molecule?

So, for example, the biosynthetic origin of Paclitaxel is terpenes?

Comment: Biosynthetic means : " has been synthesized by a vital process, and not in a lab". For example, sugar, chlorophyll, cellulose and proteins have a biosynthetic origin, because they have been produced in a living cell

Comment: Or produced in a lab by means of biosynthesis (typically using bacteria - the product of interest can even accumulate *within* the cells, from which is later separated).